# find subsequence in a string: Java

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

I have a string `hackkkerrank` and i have to find if any ***subsequence*** gives a result as `hackerrank`, if it is present then it gives result as `YES` otherwise `NO`.

Sample:

```
hereiamstackerrank: YES
hackerworld: NO
```

I don't know which `String` method should be applied, can anyone help me how to do it?

Here is my code:

```
static String hackerrankInString(String s) {
  char str[] = {
   'h','a','c','k','e','r','a','n','k'
  };
 while (s.length() >= 10) {
  for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
   for (char c: str) {
    if (s.indexOf(c)) {
     System.out.println("YES");
    } else {
     System.out.println("NO");
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to find if input string contains `hackerrank` ? If yes, then this one is not making sense: `hereiamstackerrank: YES hackerworld: NO`. Please add more details to your question.

Comment: Also your code has formatting problems and its also incomplete, also the variable `str` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: *"i don't know which string method should be applied"* I would suggest [`length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--) and [`charAt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-), but why don't you look through [all the methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#method.summary) listed in the javadoc of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to decide for yourself?

Comment: @AmithKumar yes i am trying to find subsequence not substring.

Comment: `hereiamstackerank` should return `YES` or `NO` ? Since it only has one `r`.

Comment: @Andreas yes you are right, but i have tried all the relevant methods, but no one gives correct output. I am trying to check if the subsequence "hackerrank" is present in string "hereiamckerrrank" or not?

Comment: @AmithKumar no.. it contains 2 r. Please look at the sample i have posted on the top.

Comment: The value of `s` is never changing so you are going to have an endless loop

Comment: _"I have a string "hackkkerrank" and i have to find if any subsequence gives a result as "hackerrank"... hereiamstackerrank: YES hackerworld: NO"_ -- This makes no sense assuming the normal definition of _subsequence_.  Please clarify what you mean explicitly.

Comment: @JimGarrison i am trying to check if a given subsequence present in a string or not? Here the subsequence is "hackerrank" and string is "hereiamstackerrank".

Comment: And using the normal definition of "subsequence", the string `hereimstackerrank` does not contain a subsequence equal to `hackerrank`.  I believe what you want is to determine if an ordered selection of characters within `hereimstackerrank` can be found that matches `hackerrank`, which is a totally different problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes you are right.. that is what exactly i wanted. Thanks.

Comment: @Ashit Check the below answers

Comment: @JimGarrison `hackerrank` *is* a subsequence inside `hereimstackerrank` according to normal definition of [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence): `HereimstACKERRANK`. What definition of subsequence do you consider normal? FYI: As article says: *subsequence should not be confused with substring*.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a built-in way, using regex:

```
String regex = "[^h]*+h[^a]*+a[^c]*+c[^k]*+k[^e]*+e[^r]*+r[^r]*+r[^a]*+a[^n]*+n[^k]*+k.*";
System.out.println("hereiamstackerrank".matches(regex) ? "YES" : "NO");
System.out.println("hackerworld".matches(regex) ? "YES" : "NO");
```

*Output*

```
YES
NO
```

---

You can make a generic method to check for subsequence like this:

```
public static boolean containsSubsequence(String subsequence, String text) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, j; i < subsequence.length(); i = j) {
        j = subsequence.offsetByCodePoints(i, 1);
        String ch = Pattern.quote(subsequence.substring(i, j));
        buf.append("[^").append(ch).append("]*+").append(ch);
    }
    String regex = buf.append(".*").toString();
    return text.matches(regex);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(containsSubsequence("hackerrank", "hereiamstackerrank") ? "YES" : "NO");
System.out.println(containsSubsequence("hackerrank", "hackerworld") ? "YES" : "NO");
```

*Output*

```
YES
NO
```

Of course, it is not very efficient, but it is one way to do it.

---

For a simpler and more efficient solution, that doesn't handle characters in the [Supplement­ary Planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Overview), you'd do this:

```
public static boolean containsSubsequence(String subsequence, String text) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() && j < subsequence.length(); i++)
        if (text.charAt(i) == subsequence.charAt(j))
            j++;
    return (j == subsequence.length());
}
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I found the regex quite hard to understand, for example, for `hack` my regex will simply be `.*h+.*a+.*c+.*k+.*`

Comment: @PhamTrung The regex is optimized for best performance, e.g. using `[^h]*+h` mean to match all characters up to and including the next `h`. It's better than `.*h`, because that will search until the end of the string, then backtrack until an `h` is found, try matching remainder regex from there, then backtrack more if no match, and more, and more. Not good for performance. E.g. using the regex you gave to scan `xxhxxaxxcxxkxx` takes 40 steps, but using my style of regex only takes 10 steps.

Comment: Nice to know the explanation, +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is an old fashioned looping way, which increments the starting position of the second string based upon where the last char was found

```
    String str1 = "hackerrank";
    String str2 = "hereiamstackerrank";

    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) 
    {
        boolean notfound = true;
        int x = index;
        for (; x < str2.length(); x++) {
            if (str1.charAt(i) == str2.charAt(x)) {
                notfound = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (notfound) {
            System.out.println("NO");
            return;
        }
        index = x + 1;
    }
    System.out.println("YES");
```

An in-efficient alternative is

```
    for (int i = 0; str1.length() > 0 && i < str2.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (str1.charAt(0) == str2.charAt(i)) {
            str1 = str1.substring(1);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str1.length() == 0 ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Comment: If you change the outer loop to iterate `str2` and only advance `str1` when chars match, you wouldn't need an inner loop.

Comment: Now that `substring` copies the backing array, that's not really efficient, is it?

Comment: Not efficient at all, but I rightly thought you would post your idea in your own answer

Answer (score 0):

```
static String re="";
    static String hackerrankInString(String s) {
        String pattern="[^h]*+h[^a]*+a[^c]*+c[^k]*+k[^e]*+e[^r]*+r[^r]*+r[^a]*+a[^n]*+n[^k]*+k.*";
        if(s.matches(pattern)){
            re="YES";
        }else{
            re="NO";
        }
        return re;
    }
```

Comment: Please, when you insert some code in your posts, you have to put the code in block quotes

Answer (score -1):

There's no built in function in core libraries to check `subsequence`. There's one for `substring` but none for `subsequence` you're looking for.

*You'll have to code it yourself*.

Below is the pseudo code for this:

```
1. Traverse both original string and string under test. 
2. Increment both's counter if characters are equal
3. Else increment originalString's counter only.
4. Repeat 2-3 `while` both strings are `not` empty. 
5. Given string under test is subsequence if its counter is exhausted.
```